# Importing events from MS Office 365 (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, api, ms-office

I have an intranet site for a small medical clinic, and on the front page I want to display upcoming events associated with the clinic-wide MS Office 365 email account.

I'm new to APIs, so some resources on how to get started would help.

The site is in PHP, but as I understand it, API functions can be done in JavaScript - either way is fine.

Once I can get an XML or JSON file from Microsoft, I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to format it for the site. The problem is just getting the info.

So far I have:

```
<script>
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/{email address}/events", false);
    req.send();
    console.log(req.status);
    console.log(req.StatusText);
</script>
```

The console logged:

```
"NetworkError: 401 Anonymous Request Disallowed
```

I've also tried the line `req.open("GET", "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/me/events", false{or true}/ {username}, {password});`, to which the console logged

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

Almost all the documentation I can find is directed toward individual users (employees of a company) interfacing with their 365 accounts through some web-based interface, so almost all of the urls have `/me/` in them, indicating they have authenticated somehow. But I want my PHP or JavaScript script to automatically authenticate a single user and retrieve information. I imagine this requires hard-coding the user and password somewhere, but I've found no examples like that.

I'm obviously in way over my head, but can anyone offer any advice on how I can get this done? Or read more about how APIs work? Most of the documentation out there is directed at people who already have a certain level of knowledge, which I don't have, and don't really know how to get.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing part is authentication (OAuth) to connect from your app to O365.. 
Maybe this helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bde5647a-fff1-4b51-b67b-2139de79ce4a%28Office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to authenticate against the Office 365 APIs as indicated previously. To make calls against Office 365, you must register your app for OAuth against Azure AD.

I'd suggest looking at http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis. It should guide you through setting up authentication and show you how to make the rest call.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the first part to provide the stand alone answer to the start :)